# Is sending Session from javascript safe?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Well, this is a bit weird i think to ask this question, because i am not sure if that's the place to ask that.

OK, into the question..

I have this code

```
<script>
var session = "<%= Session["User"]%>";
</script>
```

So, i was thinking, is that safe? let me tell you what i mean..

I have a web api which you can get the name, last name, age and everything about the user with his Session, can i send this web api this session and use it?

Is that a safe thing to do ? in matter of securiy? if not, is there any better way?

EDIT 1:

What am i trying to aaccomplish? simple, i will store the UserId in the session, the UserId will Guid, when the user is loogin in the javascript can send post to an API server to get info, the API will send the UserId from the session.

Is That ok?

Comment: probably not. if that's all you're using to validate that someone is in a session, then it could be intercepted.

Comment: What would i should do, can you tell?

Comment: What is your purpose in executing that line of code?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you're trying to actually accomplish? Why must you feel like you need to send Session variables to other pages?

Comment: IMO, it is much better to keep only session ID and if you want to show username of logged user then simply take it from DB. As a side note, as more data you keep in a session as more it affects performance. In most cases session is supposed to be just ID, and not complete data container. Your line of code does not look dangerous, but it looks weird :)

Comment: Look at the edit,thanks!

Comment: I would like to get an answer too. any one?

Comment: Remember that everything that is visible in javascript could be intercepted by hackers. So, it is not wise to make the UserId from session the only piece of info used by the API. It is better to use something like OAuth2 with a token that your API can unencrypt and parse to get values. The key for encrypting / unencrypting would be only available server side - hidden from the prying eyes of hackers.

Comment: I don't really understand, what can you add to header that hacker cant add? nothing. so how can i talk from javascript to server secure?

Answer (score 2):

Workflow that you describe looks fine. For me it seems safe to use some ID to get more information about some user, especially if this is supposed to be an API, at least, Facebook API uses such principle not being afraid of some hackers :)

My main concern here is the coding style when you try to mix code and view which is not good. If you really need to share some information between client and server sides then I would go with one of these options.

**Option # 1** - Cookies

[What is the difference between a Session and a Cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623815/what-is-the-difference-between-a-session-and-a-cookie)

You can keep some simple information in a cookie and get it this way :

- Client : $.cookie('ID')
- Server : Response.Cookies["ID"]

In this case there is no need to put in a mess your client side JS with C# code and cookies will be saved on users PC which means that nobody will see them except him.

**Option # 2** - Templates

- Server : put all needed information into hidden form or ViewState
- Client : take information from hidden form using HTML selectors

**Straight answer :**

In general, if you worry only about safety then **it is fine to use this code**, it should not break security of your site.

Although, personally I do not like this approach because :

- you will mix code and view, MVC was created to split them
- it is not clear where exactly in your view you will put this code and thus it is not clear how you are going to check that this variable was initialized
- it may happen that you will put there some value that will break JS syntax and will cause JS error

In my personal opinion, I would replace it with one of the mentioned options.

**Option 1** - MVC + JQuery + Cookie Example

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string demo = Request.QueryString["MyNameSpace.ID"]; // get value from client
    Response.Cookies["MyNameSpace.ID"].Value = "server"; // change value in response
    return View();
}
```

Then in your JS file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {            // make sure server rendered page
    var ID = $.cookie('MyNameSpace.ID');  // get cookie value from server
    $.cookie('MyNameSpace.ID', 'client'); // update, on the next request server will get it
});
```

**Option 2** - MVC + JQuery + Templates Example

```
public class OptionsModel // View Model
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index() // Controller
{
    OptionsModel options = new OptionsModel();
    options.ID = "server";
    return View(options);
}
```

Your view :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<OptionsModel>" %>

<%=Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ID, new { @class = "MyNameSpace:ID" })%>
<%=Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.User, new { @class = "MyNameSpace:User" })%>
```

Then in your JS file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {              // make sure server rendered page
    var options = $('[class^=MyNameSpace]') // get values from hidden fields
    options[0] = 'client';                  // update data
    $.ajax({ data : options });             // create handler to send data back to server
});
```

Examples for Web Forms do not differ significantly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean,. is that good way? or don't do it?

Answer (score -1):

The code you have posted will be rendered on the page as so when it hits the client (assuming you are using ASP.NET

```
<script>
     var session = "John Smith";
</script>
```

This is due to the use of the server side scripting tags <%= %> (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961121.aspx)

As a note its probably not the best thing in the world to fully expose the session to javascript if that is your intention. At the end of the day it depends what you are storing in there and using it for (but ASP.NET will also use it for certain things) but exposing it just opens another area for someone to attack.

http://www.owasp.org is a great place to learn more about securing your website.

Comment: This does not expose the session to JavaScript. It exposes the users's name (or whatever `Session["User"].ToString()` produces). It's not possible to expose "the session" to JavaScript because there _is_ no such thing. One could expose the session ID, but that's no big deal since it's already exposed in a cookie.

Comment: Which is what I highlight in the script tags. The rest is just a general warning on exposing information from a website that might not need to be exposed. Just because a session id is already exposed do you really want to fly it like a flag?

Comment: I think it's ok to assume a base level of intelligence on the part of hackers. Otherwise, you run the risk of underestimating them.

Comment: No one said anything about underestimating the abilities of hackers. This is more a case of security best practice.